# change mysql output column width

Tags: mysql, formatting, output

Is there a way to change mysql column output width like in sql:

```
SET LINESIZE 50000;
```

I am not looking for ending the query with \G because I want to keep it in column format. I have seen a few answers using

```
pager less
```

but that just cuts off anything that goes past my terminal size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for a given column, just return the first X characters? You could use the [LEFT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left):

`SELECT LEFT(your_column, 50000) FROM your_table;`

Comment: that command doesn't work with for example: show columns from table; i was wondering if there is something that I could do once and have it apply all the time

Comment: You could play with the pager by adapting one of these: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/01/21/fun-with-the-mysql-pager-command/